# How to restrict taxonomy for user

Tags: content-hub

I have created a new `Taxonomy` called "McDonalds".
After uploading an image, there is a field `Restricted Access`, which shows all existing `Taxonomies` when logged in as the superuser.

[image]

But, when I log in as another user (*myApp_creator*), the modal is blank.

[image]

I would like to show only one option ("McDonalds") in the `Restricted Access` field for this new user.  How to do that.

This is how I have created the new user:

[image]

The two custom User Groups are exactly as `M.Builtin.Creators` & `M.Builtin.Editors`.

Also created a new User Group called "McDonaldsUG", which has a rule - M.DRM.Restricted with condition as the `AccessGroup:McDonalds"  and permission as "Read".

[image]

I tried adding this McDonaldUG to the user at the top level, as a subset checking with "Any" & "All" combinations. No luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

@Abhinav Kumar Singh from the community helped me with this.

1. For the `User Group` called "McDonaldsUG", I deleted all existing rules.
2. Added a rule for "AccessGroup". Selected "AccessGroup" as condition & "McDonalds" as Value. In the Permissions, selected "Read".
3. For the user, moved all the User Groups including McDonaldsUG from `All` to `Any` condition.